# Перевод строки с шестнадцатеричным числом в число

Tags: java, строки

У меня возникли проблемы с переводом из строки в число.
Всё было бы просто, если бы в строке были числа в 10-ричной системе счисления, но дело в том что функция у меня возвращает строку в 16-ричной системе счисления.

Вот сама строка: *F2C22A3B6CA109A46D9B45DB3F2C578A*.

Как мне перевести её в число?

Comment: Как пробовали и какие ошибки получали?

Comment: А доки читать пробовали? [`Integer.parseInt('FF', 16 );`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: @BOPOH Оформите полноценным ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Похоже у вас проблема, так как число, которое вы хотите преобразовать слишком большое даже для типа `long`, а нецелочисленные типы не поддерживают такие преобразования. Если никто ничего лучше не посоветует, то парсить самому [по формуле](http://vestikinc.narod.ru/AB/hex_dec_tr.htm).

Comment: @pavlofff, [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) вроде может сам конвертировать из hex (`long value = new BigInteger("d1bc4f7154ac9edb", 16).longValue();`), а с такими большими числами он нормально работает?

Comment: @BOPOH Да, вы правы, только приведение к `long` здесь не нужно, так как оно не вмещает такое большое число. Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ответ из комментариев @BOPOH

Для целых чисел до 32-ух битов используется следующая конструкция:

```
String str = "F2C22A3B";
int num = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
System.out.println(""+num);
```

Для целых чисел до 64-ех битов:

```
String str = "F2C22A3B6CA109A4";
long num = Long.parseLong(str, 16);
System.out.println(""+num);
```

Для чисел более 64-ех битов:

```
String str = "F2C22A3B6CA109A46D9B45DB3F2C578A";
BigInteger num = new BigInteger(str, 16);
System.out.println(""+num);
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ решил мою проблему

Comment: У меня строка ```Long.parseLong("e19fdcd0c87a6e8e",16)``` выдает ошибку ```java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e19fdcd0c87a6e8e"````

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях подсказали что строковое представление числа в 16-чной системе счисления можно перевести в тип `int` с помощью `Integer.parseInt('FF', 16 )`. Но это верно только для чисел которые помещаются в соответствующую разрядную сетку. Обычно тип `int` занимает 32 бита - числа от 0x00000000 до 0xFFFFFFFF,  для 64-битного целого - числа от 0x0000000000000000 до 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. В вашем же случае строковое представление числа заведомо больше - это число 128-битное. В этом случае Вам необходимо работать с длинной арифметикой. Но лучше всего правильно разобраться с изначально поставленной задачей (не той что в вопросе). Скорее всего нету необходимости переводить строковое число в целочисельный тип.