# Перевод из шестнадцатеричной системы в десятичную java

Tags: java

Я не понимаю, как в данном примере переводится число.
То-есть, не понимаю последнего шага... Из строки мы берем символ, потом вычисляем его индекс, соответственно изменяем буквы из 16-системы в числа, а потом... Как потом ? Все работает правильно, я проверял (компилировал), но если на бумажке сижу и считаю, вообще не выходит у меня, как программа приходит к верному решению... Может кто немножко пошагово разложить как верно работает посл. строка при вычислении val переменной.

```
    public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        val = 16*val + d;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Вам интересен этот алгоритм с точки зрения прикладных знаний? В Java есть [более гуманные способы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461008/177345) конвертации между разными системами счисления.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Число в шестнадцатеричной системе, например `A1B`, переводится в десятичную по формуле `A*16^2 + 1*16 + B`, где `A=10`, а `B=11`. Результат `2587`. Однако вместо того, чтобы основание системы счисления `16` возводить в степень на каждом шаге, можно применить метод, сродни [схеме Горнера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) для вычисления значений полиномов в точке. То есть `(A*16 + 1)*16 + B`. Таким образом, на нулевой итерации цикла будет вычислено `val=0*16+A=10`, затем `val=10*16+1=161`, затем `161*16+11=2587`.

Собственно, на пальцах идея такая: добавление очередной цифры в конец строки, это эквивалентно умножению на 16 и прибавлению этой цифры к сумме. Аналогично ведь и в десятичной системе счисление: добавление цифры означает домножить на 10 и прибавить цифру: `123 = 12*10 + 3`