# Конвертировать "#FF00FFFF" в 0x00FFFFFF

Tags: java, color, hex

Как бы суть в заголовке. надо конвертировать строку "#AARRGGBB" в шестнадцатеричное число *0xrrggbbaa*.

Comment: Я тоже не могу понять. Берешь 1 и 2 символ, кидаешь в конец строки. А потом заменяешь # на 0x

Comment: Если вам нужно просто числовое значение, которое представлено в виде  строки, то не важно, в какой системе счисления оно находится, такие условности критичны только человеку. Просто [преобразуйте строку в число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461008/177345).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно сделать так, воспользовавшись тем фактом, что цвет занимает все 32 бита `int`'а (или 8 шестнадцатеричных цифр).

```
// int src = 0xAARRGGBB; // это число, если у вас не число, сделайте число
int dest = (src << 8) | (src >>> 24);
//        __RRGGBB00      000000AA________
//                 RRGGBBAA
```

- `_` обозначает "вылезшие" за пределы числа в результате сдвигов цифры.
- `>>>` (не `>>`) используется, чтобы слева наверняка были вставлены **нули**, независимо от того, какое значение на старшем бите `AA`.
- Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что число не имеет ни малейшего представления о том, десятичное оно или шестнадцатеричное. Потому что система счисления является характеристикой не самого числа, а только его **текстового представления**.

Comment: Какой-то велосипед.

Comment: @Flippy почему же велосипед-то?

Comment: Кстати, плюсы компилируют подобный код в одну инструкцию процессора (не считая загрузки и сохранения в переменную). Наверняка JVM тоже умеет такой код хорошо оптимизировать.

Answer (score -1):

```
 String func  (String abc){    //abc это входные данные
    int inc=3;                 
    char [] arrayCh;           //char массив для работы по индексно
    arrayCh=abc.toCharArray(); //String переводим в символьный массив
    String temp="0x";          //temp задаем начальное значение

    while (inc<abc.length()){  //посимвольно копируем с 3 индекса

        temp+=arrayCh[inc];
    }
    temp+=arrayCh[1]+arrayCh[2];// вконец добавляем 2 и 3 символ

    return temp;                //возвращаем новый String
}
```

попробуй так

Comment: Пишите более развернутые ответы. Поясните что, как и где делает этот алгоритм.

Comment: Нужно **число** в 16 ричном формате, а не строка

Answer (score -3):

```
String a="#Fe00FFFF";
long orig = Long.parseLong(a.substring(1),16);
long result = (orig&0x0000FFFF)|(orig&0xFF000000)|(orig&0x00FF0000);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: это псевдокод?)

Comment: В том то и дело что на выходе должно быть число...

Comment: @Flippy тогда вот так

Comment: Или вот так `Integer.parseInt("RRGGBBAA", 16)` без `#` или `0x`

Comment: Не работает оба ваших способа. `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Invalid int: "00FFFFFF"

Comment: Проверил, работает. Но например не работает с #ffe0e0e0

Comment: @Flippy загадка... Ну да черт с ней, со строкой, я придумал гораздо более интересный способ. Золотая пуля практически :) Обновил ответ

Comment: @Flippy Все, теперь точно работает. Это ж у вас Long, а не Integer